# Get count of multiple values in a dataset table with extra columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have the following code (from a previous question), to get a list and count of  ParentID from a datatable;

```
 var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ParentID"))
            .Select(x => new { ParentID = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
            .ToList();
```

this works perfectly, now, I'd also like list another column from the same table called "DocumentName" as part of same the results query keeping the count of ParentID but not sure how to change the code.

​

​

Comment: You are grouping rows by the `ParentID` foreign key. Is the `DocumentName` unique per each `ParentID`? if not, you need an aggregation function on that field.

Comment: thanks Amir, the DocumentName is unique per each 'ParentID'

Comment: To clarify you want DocumentName in the keys along with ParentID, so it would be multiple keys

Comment: For you to have DocumentName, as another column, either incluse that as the Key or you will get a List of its type in final result, since it will be grouped result

Comment: DocumentName is an integer field, that's pretty strange design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aggregate function, like `Max`

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ParentID"))
            .Select(x => new
                    {
                       ParentID = x.Key,
                       DocumentName = x.Max(y => y.Field<int>("DocumentName")),
                       Count = x.Count()
                    }).ToList();
```